# Putting variable in multiple path

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to javascript and have a code right here which works really great. But it puts the variable k only to one path. I also want to add it to few more paths.

This here with one path works great.

```
function checkpath() {
   var db = admin.database();
    var ref =  db.ref('placeID/here:pds:place:276u0wuu-237aa2a/' + messageID + '/notification');
    ref.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const keyArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        return Promise.all(keyArray.map(k => db.ref('/user/' + k + '/notification/' + subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID)));
      } else {
        console.log('No data available');
        return null;
        
      }
    })
}
```

This one does not work. It gives me the error: "Exception from a finished function: ReferenceError: k is not defined"

```
function checkpath() {
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref =  db.ref('placeID/here:pds:place:276u0wuu-237aa2a/' + messageID + '/notification');
    ref.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const keyArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        return Promise.all(keyArray.map(k => 
            
            (db.ref('/user/' + k + '/notification/' + subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID)),
            (db.ref('/user/' + k + '/notification/' + subMessageID + '/userTime/').set(userTime))
        
        ));
      } else {
        console.log('No data available');
        return null;
        
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your callback function returns two Objects (here two Promises) separated by a comma.

Let's illustrate the problem with the following code snippets:

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(x => (x * 2, x * 3)); // See the parenthesis
console.log(map1);
```

returns `> Array [3, 12, 27, 48]`

because the anonymous callback function returns the second expression i.e. `x * 3`.

Now if you remove the parenthesis as follows

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2, x * 3); 
console.log(map1);
```

it returns `Error: x is not defined` because with just `x *3`, `x` is not defined (while it is defined within `x => x * 2`)

---

However, in your case, you cannot add parenthesis because you want to get the **two** Promises added to the Array you're going to pass to `Promise.all()`.

Therefore you need to do something along the following lines, by pushing the promises in an Array:

```
  function checkpath() {
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref(
      'placeID/here:pds:place:276u0wuu-237aa2a/' +
        messageID +
        '/notification'
    );
    return ref.get().then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const keyArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        const promises = [];
        keyArray.forEach((k) => {
          promises.push(
            db
              .ref(
                '/user/' +
                  k +
                  '/notification/' +
                  subMessageID +
                  '/subMessageID/'
              )
              .set(subMessageID)
          );
          promises.push(
            db
              .ref(
                '/user/' +
                  k +
                  '/notification/' +
                  subMessageID +
                  '/userTime/'
              )
              .set(userTime)
          );
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);  // Not sure you need to return anything here because the set() method returns a Promise<void>...
      } else {
        console.log('No data available');
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ok now I understand it. Great it also works. Last question is there a way to do an exception from k? For example if there is a string called "test" K should ignore or skip it?

Comment: In the `forEach` block you can very well check with an `if` block if the Promise shall be pushed to the `promises` array.